# F# vector rowvector multiplication issue

Tags: .net, vector, matrix, f#

I need to multiply a Vector by a RowVector to get a Matrix as the result. But the F# libraries do not have such an implementation for the * operator. How can I do this?

```
//wj(t+1)=wj(t) - a * (yk-dk)* xjk
let weightsDeltaRule (w : matrix, x : vector, y : vector, d : vector) (a : float) = 
    let delta = y - d
    w - a * (Vector.transpose x) * delta
```

**UPD:**

```
vector<'T> *  rowvec<'T> -> matrix<'T>
rowvec<'T> * vector<'T> -> 'T
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with F# vectors and matrices, but I'd suggest turning the two vectors into matrices with one column and one row respectively, and then using matrix multiplication.

Comment: @Mark: i think vector is more appropriate type than single column matrix...

Comment: In light of John's answer, there is no need for my suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you think the powerpack doesn't implement `Vector * RowVector = Matrix`?

Taken from `matrix.fsi`

```
/// Multiply a column vector and a row vector to produce a matrix
static member ( * )   : Vector<'T>    * RowVector<'T> -> Matrix<'T>
```

Comment: strange issue... vector * rowvec -> matrix but rowvec * vector -> T. can u explain this?

Comment: @DmitryMartovoi - matrix / vector multiplication is not commutative - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication